# Using SwingWorker to set a coordinate

Tags: timer, swingworker, worldwind

Right now I am absolutely stuck with a project involving WorldWind, but its a general issue with the SwingWorker and swing Timer Classes.

Basically I have a shape on a globe, that has a LatLon coordinate, and Every set amount of time, I am trying to move it along a predetermined vector in the LatLon.   Everything should be working except for the actual timer event.   I have tried using multiple things from a standard Timer, to calling System.getCurrentTimeMill() and incrementing that, and none of them have worked.

Right now, when I hit the button "Animate" it calls this function:

```
private void animate(LatLon pos) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException   {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread())
        {

            timer = new Timer(speed, this);
            timer.setInitialDelay(pause);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            while (count < 5)
            {
                timer.start();
                CircleWorker.execute();
                sphere.setLocation(pos);
                count ++;
            }

        }

    else{
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    int count = 0;

                    //timer = new Timer(speed, this);
                    timer.setInitialDelay(pause);
                    while (count < 30)
                    {
                        timer.start();
                        CircleWorker.execute();
                        count ++;
                        checker2();
                    }
                }});
```

Here is my SwingWorker:

```
SwingWorker<LatLon, Void> CircleWorker = new SwingWorker<LatLon, Void>()
            {


                @Override
                protected LatLon doInBackground() 
                {
                    //checker();


                    double lat = changeAm.getLatitude().getDegrees() + currentPos.getLatitude().getDegrees();
                    double lon = changeAm.getLongitude().getDegrees() + currentPos.getLongitude().getDegrees();
                    // sets lat lon to the amounts in each individual amount

                    currentPos = LatLon.fromDegrees(lat, lon);
                    counter ++;

                    //checker2();

                    return currentPos;
                }
                @Override
                public void done()
                {
                    //checker3();
                    currentPos = ATLANTA;
                }
            };
```

Comment: A Timer executes a TimerTask in its own thread. A Timer is asynchronous. Your code does't seem to know that. After you call `start` the first time the Timer will kick off. Subsequent calls will do very little.

Comment: The timer isn't even running at all right now from what I can tell.   The sphere just vanishes after the animate function is called.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed up the code entirely, moving away from the swing worker, and into just a swing Timer, and an action event.   My object is now moving, the issue is that I have no control over how many times this event takes place.   I would like to stop it after say, 30 or 100, or how ever many executions.

Current code:

```
    private void animate() throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException   {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        currentPos = ATLANTA;


        ActionListener sphereAction  = new ActionListener()
        {
            private int count = 0;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                double lat = changeAm.getLatitude().getDegrees() + currentPos.getLatitude().getDegrees();
                double lon = changeAm.getLongitude().getDegrees() + currentPos.getLongitude().getDegrees();
                // sets lat lon to the amounts in each individual amount

                currentPos = LatLon.fromDegrees(lat, lon);


                //checker2();

                sphere.setLocation(currentPos); 
                setCount(getCount() + 1);
            }
            public int getCount() {
                return count;
            }
            public void setCount(int count) {
                this.count = count;
            }

        };

        Timer timer = new Timer(speed, sphereAction);
        timer.start();

        //Obviously this isn't working.
        if (count == 10)
            timer.stop();
```